# Gerar imagem com iniciais do nome, igual o Hotmail, Skype, Gmail

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um código de gerar imagem a partir de texto para o cadastro de clientes, para os clientes que não fizessem upload de imagem, ficasse as iniciais do nome e sobrenome como imagem, igual ao gmail, hotmail e etc. O problema é que, temos a `$nome` que contém o nome completo da pessoa, eu não estou conseguindo pegar somente a primeira letra do 1º e 2º nome, por exemplo, "Thomas Franklin" pegar somente "TH" e salvar como imagem no banco e hosp. O código de geração de imagem eu já tenho, porém a parte em que faz a seleção das letras e salvar a imagem não estou conseguindo.

Código:

```
<?php
class GerarAvatar {
  function __construct()
  {
    $nome = $_GET['nome'];
    $model = $_GET['model'];
    $this->nome_para_avatar = $nome;
    $this->mod_para_avatar = $model;
  }
  public function gerar() 
  {
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");  
    $texto = $this->nome_para_avatar;
    $mod_escolhido = $this->mod_para_avatar;
    $add_extensao = '../imgs/' . $mod_escolhido . '.jpg';
    $font_path = '../fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf';
    if ($mod_escolhido == 'vermelho') {
      $modelo = imagecreatefromjpeg($add_extensao);
      $bg_default = imagecolorallocate($modelo, 255, 255, 255);
      imagettftext($modelo, 20, 0, 30, 55, $bg_default, $font_path, $texto);
    }elseif ($mod_escolhido == 'azul') {
      $modelo = imagecreatefromjpeg($add_extensao);
      $bg_default = imagecolorallocate($modelo, 0, 0, 0);
      imagettftext($modelo, 12, 0, 10, 200, $bg_default, $font_path, $texto);
    }elseif($mod_escolhido !== 'vermelho'){
     $modelo = imagecreatefromjpeg('../imgs/cinza.jpg');
     $bg_default = imagecolorallocate($modelo, 255, 255, 255);
     imagettftext($modelo, 20, 0, 30, 55, $bg_default, $font_path, $texto);
   }
   imagejpeg($modelo);
   imagedestroy($modelo);
 }
}
$gerar = new GerarAvatar();
$gerar->gerar();   
?>
```

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poderia fazer desse jeito, utilizando a função explode e pegando o 1 caractere do primeiro e segundo array

```
$array = explode(" ", $nome);

$iniciais = $array[0][0] . $array[1][0];
```

Para o envio de arquivo é aconselhável que se armazene apenas o caminho relativo das imagens no banco de dados, como por exemplo:

```
 $nome =  md5($_FILES['imagem']['name']);

 $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];

 $destino = "/var/www/html/" . $nome;

 move_uploaded_file( $arquivo_tmp, $destino  );
```

E no banco de dados salve apenas a variável `$nome`

Comment: Você é demais cara. Algora só falta conseguir salvar na hosp. kaksaks

Comment: Resolveu 50% do problemas, adushds mas vou marcar sim.

Comment: salvar a imagem na pasta

Comment: Cara, consegui kaskask

Comment: @ThomasFranklin, caso tenha outro problema, crie outra pergunta.

Comment: @vmsouza, eu sei, essa pergunta engloba esses dois problemas.